# How to wrap a Node `EventEmitter` to be able to consume it as an `AsyncIterator` that terminates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, generator, ixjs

I'm trying to use a XML stream parsing API ([`xml-flow`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-flow)) that exposes a Node `EventEmitter` that emits a bunch of `tag` events for the tags I'm interested in, and an `end` event when it finishes reading the document.

I'd like to be able to munge this using [Interactive Extensions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/IxJS), but I can't figure out how to convert this to an async iterable that ends; `ix` only has`fromEvent`/`fromEventPattern` which don't seem to have a way to handle an "end" event.

Trying just:

```
import * as aix from 'ix/asynciterable';
import flow from 'xml-flow';

const iterTags = aix.fromEvent(flow(...), 'tag:foo');
console.log('max', aix.max(iterTags));
```

produces no output, while adding a `.pipe(tap(console.debug))` to print the values being iterated over shows me the stream is actually being processed correctly.

Is there a way I can wire up the `end` event to cause the iterator to `return` so this works correctly?

Comment: Maybe wrap it into a readable stream, [which are iterable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to create an async iterable, by using some parts from `rxjs`, instead of the corresponding `ixjs` versions.

Whatever you do with rxjs you can always pipe from `ix.from` to convert observable to an async iterable.

Input:

```xml
  <root>
      <foo>
        <name>Bill</name>
        <id>1</id>
        <age>27</age>
      </foo>
      <foo>
        <name>Sally</name>
        <id>2</id>
        <age>40</age>
      </foo>
      <foo>
        <name>Kelly</name>
        <id>3</id>
        <age>37</age>
      </foo>
    </root>
```

code:

```js
const {fromEvent} = require('rxjs');
const {takeUntil, tap, map} = require('rxjs/operators');
const ai = require('ix/asynciterable');

const [aiFrom, aiMax] = [ai.from, ai.max];


const flow = require('xml-flow');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const inFile = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'test.xml'));


const eventEmitter = flow(inFile);
const iterTags = aiFrom(
        fromEvent(eventEmitter, 'tag:foo')
            .pipe(takeUntil(fromEvent(eventEmitter, 'end')))
            .pipe(tap(console.log), 
                  map(o=>o.age))
    );


aiMax(iterTags).then((v)=>console.log("max age:", v));

// This works also
// (async()=>{
//     for await(el of iterTags){
//         console.log(el)
//     }
// })();
```

output:

```
{ '$name': 'foo', name: 'Bill', id: '1', age: '27' }
{ '$name': 'foo', name: 'Sally', id: '2', age: '40' }
{ '$name': 'foo', name: 'Kelly', id: '3', age: '37' }
max age: 40
```

Comment: oh, roundabout but nice